# Can anyone explain how this code INSERTS data into a database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can someone explain to me how this code works and how I am inserting this data into the database? I Java two Java files. The first piece of code is located in the first Java file and the second is located in the second Java file. Why am I passing the following parameters ImageID, currentDay, v.getID. Then when I call the insertNewRoutine function it is using the parameters int activityResourceID, String day and int slot? Confused about why it's using that?Thanks in advance!

```
boolean routineInserted = myDb.insertNewRoutine(ImageID, currentDay, v.getId());
                if (routineInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(MondayRoutineEdit.this, "Activity Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MondayRoutineEdit.this, "Activity Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

public boolean insertNewRoutine(int activityResourceID, String day, int slot)

{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + RoutineTable + " WHERE DayID ='" + day + "' AND SlotID =" + slot);
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn2, day);
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn3, activityResourceID);
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn4, slot);
    long result = db.insert(RoutineTable, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry what I meant was why am I passing the following parameters ImageID, currentDay, v.getID. Then when I call the insertNewRoutine function it is using the parameters int activityResourceID, String day and int slot? Confused about why it's using that?

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(RoutineColumn2, day);
contentValues.put(RoutineColumn3, activityResourceID);
contentValues.put(RoutineColumn4, slot);
long result = db.insert(RoutineTable, null, contentValues);
```

You are population the content values (they are going to be inserted as VALUES in sql) with function paramaters.

This method call is responsible for insertion.

> SQLiteDatabase.class exposes methods to manage a SQLite database.

Reference to the official android documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)